# Does CloudFoundry support multiple containers per app?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, cloud-foundry, amazon-ecs

A [Kubernetes Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/) and an [AWS ECS Task Definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definitions.html) both support multiple different container images: each instance of the pod / task will run all images as containers together.

Does CloudFoundry support a similar concept to allow apps that consist of multiple, separate processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

No. You can only run a single container per application instance.

**Longer Answer**

Most of the answers are quickly pointing you to PKS, however Cloud Foundry itself is outside of that.

Cloud Foundry runs each application via Diego. Each application runs as a standalone container on a diego-cell. This is different from Kubernetes which you think of Pods or groups of colocated containers.

Cloud Foundry allows you to run multiple instances of each container, but I believe this is different from what you are asking.

**Workaround**

You may not be able to run multiple containers, but you can run multiple processes. For an example of this, check out how [CF-FaaS runs](https://github.com/poy/cf-faas/blob/master/cmd/cf-faas/run.sh). It uses the [CF-Space-Security](https://github.com/poy/cf-space-security) processes in a collocated scheme.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, CloudFoundry has a community project for container orchestration tools based on Kubernetes, so that will accept pods the same way Kubernetes does.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.cloudfoundry.org/container-runtime/)

CloudFoundry also has a `CF Application Runtime` which is pretty much their PaaS that allows you to deploy applications [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) style which under the hood run as 'containers'. It's not clear from the docs what type of containers, but I presume you could find out more reading the code, but that's not exposed to the users, neither it's exposed as Pods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I actually read the article but am still not sure: did CF now replace their container runtime with Kubernetes or does "Kubernetes with Bosh" remain a community project? CF is more than just "Kubernetes with Bosh", so does that refer to a full distribution? Will it become the longterm, official CF distribution or remain just an alternative one?

Comment: > did CF now replace their...?  It doesn't appear, but it could be the long-term plan. > "Kubernetes with Bosh". It is a community project. > CF is more than just "Kubernetes with Bosh", so does that refer to a full distribution?. Yes.

Comment: Reading more on cfcr ("Kubernetes with Bosh" project) I do not think it is a full CF distribution. It can work with a full distribution, but since CF and Kubernetes solve similar problems (aggregated logs, routing,...) cfcr does not seem to contain the entire CF stack. Therefore I do not think it's correct that `CloudFoundry's container orchestration tools are based on Kubernetes` - that seems only true for cfcr which does not seem equal to the core, full CF stack.

Comment: I think they had an older orchestration not based on Kubernetes. tbh, their docs are bit confusing.

Comment: I agree the docs are confusing, but I still think CF itself is not using Kubernetes

Comment: I meant CF new orchestration tool. The original thing uses Diego and Diego cell as described in the other answer. Did you downvote?

Comment: I understand what you mean and I appreciate your thoughts but I think the way your answer is currently phrased is not correct: `Actually, CloudFoundry's new container orchestration tools are based on Kubernetes,`. They are not. There is a community project that uses CF Bosh with Kubernetes. CF still uses Diego.

Answer (score 0):

Pivotal now provides PAS - Pivotal Application Service, which is the traditional PaaS.

As a developer, I `cf push` my archive, the platform creates the container, and the Diego Orchestrator run my application. And yes, I can run multiple instances of my app.

PKS - Pivotal Container Service (cool kids spell with 'K'), is Pivotal's implementation of Kubernetes. It is CaaS - Container as a Service. As a developer, I create my own container - a docker container, or a vendor provides me a container, and PKS runs the container in a POD, inside a PKS cluster.

Next one coming out, some time in next 3 - 6 months, from Pivotal is PFS - Pivotal Functional Service. It is Pivotal's implementation of Function as a Service. As a developer, I can create and deploy a function to PFS. I have to identify the triggers for this function, based on which PFS will spin up new instances of the function, and when done, destroy it.

How you use what, depends on your use case.

This [deck](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TCxiS3m0X9zlX1XEsMzihUulpFyS_ndx/view) is for the presentation at Dallas Cloud Native Meetup's last session. Parth did a great job simplifying and explaining the differences and how you choose. Hope you can access it. Take a look.

Comment: Sorry but I think this is a misunderstanding of the question: I did not mean `run multiple instances of my app` but multiple different containers as one app. And as pointed out by the other answer PKS does not equal CF to my understanding

Comment: As a best practice, you want one container one app. In K8s, that would equate to one container, one pod. There are some edge cases, where you can have more than one container in a pod. CF does not support that. And PKS is K8s on Bosh. But bottom line it is CaaS. CF runtime is PaaS.

Comment: I appreciate your thoughts but bottom line is your current answer does not answer the question correctly. PKS is not CF and CF Diego does not support what I described to my current understanding. Whether having multiple containers per app is good practice or not is another question, but ECS and Kubernetes support it for a reason.